# For a given $3\times3$ matrix $A$, find $\beta$ such that $A^7-(\beta -1)A^6-\beta A^5$ is singular

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

> If $$A^7-(\beta -1)A^6-\beta A^5$$ is a singular   matrix find $\beta$, where $$A=
> \begin{bmatrix}\beta  & 0 & 1 \\
> -1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 3 & 1 & 2 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

My attempt

Let $A^7-(\beta -1)A^6-\beta A^5$ be $B$
taking the determinant on both sides we get $|A^7|-(\beta -1)|A^6| -\beta |A^5| =0 $

which means $A^2 -(\beta-1)A-\beta =0$
which is $(|A|-\beta)(|A|-1)=0$
which means $A=1 \text{or}  A=\beta$

now $|A|=-1$
which means $\beta=-1$.

however, the answer is $\frac{1}{3}$ why am I wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot  @user1551

Comment: The determinant is not "additive".

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out by the other answer, the determinant function is not linear. In general, $|A^7-(\beta -1)A^6-\beta A^5|$ is not equal to $|A|^7-(\beta -1)|A|^6-\beta |A|^5$.

However, one may observe that $A$ is always nonsingular, regardless of the value of $\beta$. Therefore $A^7-(\beta -1)A^6-\beta A^5$ is singular if and only if $A^2-(\beta -1)A-\beta I=(A-\beta I)(A+I)$ is singular. In other words, it is singular if and only if at least one of $A-\beta I$ or $A+I$ is singular. You may continue from here.

Comment: Thanks! Got it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep an eye: determinant is not linear! You have to compute the powers of the matrix, do the computations and finally take the determinant.

Or better, you can take common factor ($A^5$) and then apply determinant.

Comment: Thanks! So there is no way to avoid  computing $A^2$, is there?

Answer (score 1):

> If $$A^7-(\beta -1)A^6-\beta A^5$$ is a singular   matrix find $\beta$, where $$A=
> \begin{bmatrix}\beta  & 0 & 1 \\
> -1 & 0 & 0 \\
> 3 & 1 & 2 \\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$

Since $A^7-(\beta -1)A^6-\beta A^5$ is singular, it's determinant value is zero,

$$|A^7-(\beta -1)A^6-\beta A^5|=0$$

$$|A^5||A^2-(\beta -1)A-\beta I|=0$$

$$|A^5||(A+I)(A-\beta I)|=0$$

$$|A^5||A+I||A-\beta I|=0$$

Note $|A|=-1$ and $|A+I|=-4$ so only $|A-\beta I|=0$

On solving, you will get the value of $\beta=\frac{1}{3}$

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use Eigendecomposition of a matrix, factorize A in terms of its own eigen vectors(at the end you may realize that you only need to deal with the eigen value matrix )  and eigen values matrix.

from the given matrix equation we should have : $λ^7 - (β−1)λ^6 - βλ^5 = 0 $

and the requirement on the Eigenvalues :  det(**A** - λ**I**) = 0

β can be found by solving the above equations,

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I don't know this yet. Thanks for the suggestion anyway